# How to restrict access to a Servlet via browser

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using the following jquery codes to load a Servlet inside a DIV.

```
$.get('Test',function(responseText){
      $("#test").html(responseText);
});
```

The elements brought from this Servlet will use the css file including in this webpage.

But if I type in my browser ..../myProject/Test

It will display what this Servlet is meant to display, but with no css file, it will look bad.

How to restrict someone from accessing this Servlet via browser?

Comment: Just don't provide a link to this page. No one will browse the source code of the page, discover the URL, call it, and then complain that the result looks bad.

Comment: But is this common? it feels like I'm doing it in a bad way, I've never searched source codes to find the names of Servlets and access them, but I just wanna know if I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: Doing AJAX requests and loading portions of HTML pages is common. No problem about that. Whether the portion of HTML is generated using a servlet or a JSP doesn't change anything: if the URL is accessible, it's accessible.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you are fetching something using AJAX, you **are** accessing it via browser.

You can set some special HTTP header in AJAX call, but it's not secure by any means. However on the server side you can recognize this special header and if not present, refuse or return some different content.

Comment: Is my approach correct of loading contents from a servlet? I was using scriplets in the beginning, then they told me to fetch these stuff from the server not on the client's side, so is this the correct thing to do ?

Comment: @user1665700: scriptlets are working on the server side. In your solution you are fetching a piece of page (some content) on the client side and modifying the page on the fly in the browser. Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: First I tried something like this in index.jsp:

<div>
<%   Connection...Statement...ResultSet....
     While(rset.next()).... { %>
<div....
<% } %>

I used scriplets like that, I was told that I must evade using scriplets, so I moved to a servlet, inside the servlet I do the same thing but instead of <%%> for java codes, I use out.println() for HTML codes.

Comment: Then no, you're clearly not doing the right thing. HTML generation is the job of the view, implemented as a JSP. Database access is the job of a DAO layer, called via the service layer from the controller, which should be implemented in Java, as a servlet or action of an MVC framework. Read about MVC, and choose a framework (Stripes, Play, Spring MVC, Struts2, ...)

Comment: @user1665700: the "pro" way to do this is having a servlet that does the business logic and then forwards (not redirects) to a JSP that barely renders the data using JSTL. Doesn't seem like AJAX has anything to do here.